# How to wait for an async event in Espresso?

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I am confused that Espresso seems to be a little inconsistent when handling failures.

What I'm trying to achieve is a retry check for a certain string to be displayed. A button click kicks off an async operation that should complete within some time frame, and I could successfully put a try catch block around a check whether some element exists or not:

```
try {
    onView(withId(fieldIdToBeAvailable))
            .inRoot(isDialog())
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
catch (NoMatchingViewException nmve) {
    // ok, retry this or fail
    retry();
}
```

which would throw an `NoMatchingViewException` and retry this with some sort of loop, but Espresso does not throw an exception if I try to check for a matching text like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.sync_status))
                .check(matches(withText("Logged in")));
```

The only thing that happens is an `android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError:`

How would someone write a retry concept around that? When I put a failureHandler in place I cannot throw out of it (so I would catch the exception instead of the evaluation of the AssertionFailed error) since `handle` does not allow a throw:

```
        onView(withId(R.id.sync_status)).withFailureHandler(new FailureHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(Throwable error, Matcher<View> viewMatcher)
            {
                // Compiler error: Unhandled exception
                throw new Exception("Failed, try again");
            }
        }).check(matches(withText("Logged in")));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use idling resources to handle async ops https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource.html

Anyway, `Exception` is a checked exception so it should be wrapped with try-catch or method should define that exception with `throws` keyword.
To 'fix' your compiler error you may use `RuntimeException` or `Error`